# Issues with multiple AJAX calls requesting JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a code which I request data from a geoserver and display geoJSON on a map. To this request I'm using three AJAX calls like the following:

```
//JSON request   
            var WFSLayer1 = null;
            var ajax = $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset3&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayer1 = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#6e7ce8',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                            popupOptions = {
                                maxWidth: 200
                            };
                            if (feature.properties.name !== null) {
                                layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, popupOptions, {
                                    noHide: true
                                });
                            };
                            layer.bindPopup("<b>Name: </b>" + feature.properties.name + "<br><b>Description: </b>" + feature.properties.descr + "<br><b>Floors: </b>" + feature.properties.floors + "<br><b>Material: </b>" + feature.properties.material);
                            layer.on({
                                click: zoomToFeature
                            })
                        }
                    }).addTo(dataset1);
                }
            });

            var WFSLayer2 = null;
            var ajax = $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset1&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayer1 = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#e31424',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                            popupOptions = {
                                maxWidth: 200
                            };
                            if (feature.properties.name !== null) {
                                layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, popupOptions, {
                                    noHide: true
                                });
                            };
                            layer.bindPopup("<b>Name: </b>" + feature.properties.name + "<br><b>Description: </b>" + feature.properties.descr + "<br><b>Floors: </b>" + feature.properties.floors + "<br><b>Material: </b>" + feature.properties.material);
                            layer.on({
                                click: zoomToFeature
                            })
                        }
                    }).addTo(dataset2);
                }
            });

            var WFSLayer3 = null;
            var ajax = $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset2&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayer3 = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#14e324',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                            popupOptions = {
                                maxWidth: 200
                            };
                            if (feature.properties.name !== null) {
                                layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, popupOptions, {
                                    noHide: true
                                });
                            };
                            layer.bindPopup("<b>Name: </b>" + feature.properties.name + "<br><b>Description: </b>" + feature.properties.descr + "<br><b>Floors: </b>" + feature.properties.floors + "<br><b>Material: </b>" + feature.properties.material);
                            layer.on({
                                click: zoomToFeature
                            })
                        }
                    }).addTo(dataset3);
                }
            });
```

Once requested each JSON is assigned to a specific dataset.

Now my problem: every time I open the page everything work just fine, but sometimes when I refresh the page everything breaks apart. For example some times neither data is displayed, some times data ends up on the wrong dataset. When I get this bug I get the following message in the console:

```
ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset1&maxFeatures=300&outpu…:1 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

On my research it seems that this type of error is quite common when running multiple AJAX calls. What I don't understand is why this error does not occur 100% of the time. What type of techniques can be used to fix it? I heard of `Deffered Objects` but could not apply it on my code, my expertise level on this is far from great.

[Here is the full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1bHqJ1F2TcOlzieW1G8?p=info)

Although this may tend towards a GIS question I believe that this type of issue is more related to ordinary jQuery and Asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation

> **jsonpCallback**
>
> Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests.

The function is probably undefined because jQuery is probably cleaning up after itself and deleting the function after it is called.

Remove `jsonpCallback: 'getJson',` to let jQuery generate the function names itself, then you won't overwrite your previous functions (and delete them before they get called a second time).

Comment: Wow, your response quite fixed my issue! First I deleted all the callbacks and nothing worked, then I just created unique values for each of my callback. This seems to have fixed everything!  But for the records: How do I allow jQuery to create its own names?

Comment: @RicardoOliveira — By not telling it you want a specific name, as per the last paragraph of the answer.